# How to load a .csv and Image dataset in kaggle?

Tags: image, csv, pytorch, kaggle, importdata

I've been trying Binary Classification with PyTorch on the competition called SIIM-ISIC Melanoma Classification (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/siim-isic-melanoma-classification) but I've had some problems on how to combine the images and labels. I've been trying to implement a class for loading and merging the images and their labels but for some reason the same error appeared every time I tried to run the line train[5], with 5 or another index:

*FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/kaggle/input/siim-isic-melanoma-classification/jpeg/train/ISIC_0074311'*

I can assure everyone that the paths are correctly copied and that the images are in those folders.

**The folders structure is:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HfAi.png)

**train.csv:**
image_name
patient_id
sex
age_approx
anatom_site_general_challenge
diagnosis
benign_malignant
target (0 or 1)

**train folder in jpeg folder:**
ISIC_0015719.jpg
ISIC_0052212.jpg
ISIC_0068279.jpg
ISIC_0074268.jpg
...

**My code**:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image
import torch
import torch.utils.data
from PIL import Image
```

```
class LoadDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    
    def __init__(self, csv_path, image_folder, transform = None):
        self.df           = pd.read_csv(csv_path)
        self.image_folder = image_folder
        self.transform    = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        filename = self.df.loc[index, 'image_name']
        label    = self.df.loc[index, 'target']
        image    = Image.open(os.path.join(self.image_folder, filename))

        if self.transform is not None:
            image = self.transform(image)
            
        return image, label
```

```
train = LoadDataset('/kaggle/input/images1-isic2020/train.csv', '/kaggle/input/images1-isic2020/train/train')
```

```
train[5]
```

**Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve it or another option other than an image generator to obtain each image with its label?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error suggests that `filename` is missing the ".jpg" extension. A simple fix is to add the extension manually if it's always the same format:

`filename = self.df.loc[index, 'image_name'] + ".jpg"`